# Was the insanity of kings used as an argument against monarchy?

Tags: monarchy, republic, illness

History has seen its share of mentally impaired monarchs. Some examples from the last centuries include [King George III of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_III_of_the_United_Kingdom), [Emperor Ferdinand I of Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_I_of_Austria), and [Emperor Taishō of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Taish%C5%8D). It seems natural (to me, at least) that that insanity is used as an argument against Monarchy, as opposed to a Republican form of government. My question is: was this argument against Monarchy used throughout history? If it was, then when and where it was used?

Comment: US politics suggests that this is a non argument :-) & :-(

Comment: @RussellMcMahon : EU politics also show similar [trends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPgiI46FCDU)...

Comment: One might argue that Ferdinand I abdicated because his family had a vested interest in that outcome.  On the other hand, Trump's family has a vested interest in Trump staying in power.  Perhaps you have instead an argument FOR monarchy.

Comment: @vsz: Meh, per the video's title he was just drunk there. May's struggles to cope with reality, on the other hand...

Comment: Just to clarify, George III was almost certainly **not** mad, but suffering from porphyria, although this was not known at the time.

Comment: One could argue it is as difficult to get rid of a mad President as a mad king - and there is no heir apparent ready to step into the breach!

Comment: @TheHonRose   I don't think one could argue that  as Nixon was forced to resign after a few days and for really not much while mad emperors such as caligula took much longer to remove for commiting far worse crimes.

Comment: This is an interesting question, especially noting that the founders or Han and Ming in China and Hideyoshi of Japan were all born commoners but had no problems declaring themselves emperor.  
Correct me if I'm wrong, but with the exception of Athens democracy doesn't just pop out of nowhere  it arises from formal oligarchies such as the Roman republic or are influenced by such e.g. England and US.  
There does seem to be something of a "status quo" a heaven does not permit two suns nor earth two masters so to speak.   It was not too long ago when dueling was considered an

Comment: @HaoSun 2000 years does make a difference! Until you look at the present White House... ;-)

Comment: appropriate response to an insult a far cry from freedom of expression. Living in modern society, it's often unclear how much of what we take for granted is really natural such as equality 
Also if anyone has any insights as to why democracy first arose (not counting small hunter gatherer tribes) in Athens that would be very interesting.

Comment: I don’t see why this should be an argument against monarchy. Monarchy is more than just a monarch. It’s not the monarchy that’s unfit, but that specific monarch. The same goes for *any* form of government. If a president or prime-minister is unfit for office then he would be removed and one would expect the constitution to provide formal means of removal. This of course doesn’t take into account the possibility of abuse where particular parties make accusations of insanity to remove monarchs, presidents or prime-ministers inimical to their interests.

Comment: Let's keep this to history; this is not the place to discuss current affairs.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Mental illness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mental_disorders) wasn't perceived as a medical condition until recent centuries. It became notional that it might be during the Enlightenment, and it only captured the popular imagination that it was with Freud.

There were still hereditary autocratic monarchies around then, but I'd stick my neck out and suggest that the main argument against them until that point and later revolved around their legitimacy and representativity rather than the off chance a monarch might be mentally unfit.

To the best of my knowledge, when past monarchs were mentally ill, some kind of regent or successor would often step in. Or they'd get deposed or killed, and replaced by someone more fit to reign. Or they'd simply be kept out of sight (Taishō of Japan), sidelined ([Charles VI of France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_VI_of_France)), or jailed ([Joanna of Castile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joanna_of_Castile)), while others filled the power vacuum.

The example of [Ludwig II of Bavaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_II_of_Bavaria), for instance, is instructive. He was an eccentric with extravagant spending habits. This led conspirators to get him certified as mentally unfit to rule -- this was very controversial because they did so without even examining him. His heir was his younger brother [Otto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_of_Bavaria). *He* was considered insane and unfit to rule at the time. So his uncle and cousin ended up reigning instead, until the latter deposed him outright.

The commonality here is that a mad king is temporary state of affairs, perhaps even one that can be exploited by opportunists, rather than a problem that prompts observers to question whether there should be a monarchy to begin with.

Comment: beat me too it. as long as regents exist the argument is a non-starter

Comment: Pls read some political science!  Monarchy was rejected because monarchs could not make things happen: Any change deleteriously affected some nobles' ancient rights and privileges and so were adamantly and often violently opposed.  Many kings, including John of Robin Hood and Magna Carta fame, and Charles I, who lost his head over this issue, had good ideas for bringing progress to their realms, but could not implement them due to opposition of the hereditary nobility.  Their reliance on the divine right of kings cost them everything.

Comment: @CElliott: I fail to see how what you describe doesn't fall under legitimacy and representativity.

Comment: Really, it wasn't until Wilhelm Wundt that the concept of the mind or mental phenomena was discarded from psychology and all conditions hitherto regarded as mental or spiritual were relabelled as biological.  And it's important to note that the biochemical imbalance notion [is not a serious scientific theory, and certainly not proven scientific fact](https://www.abqjournal.com/1301182/unfounded-claims-used-to-sell-drugs-for-children.html).

Comment: @CElliott Charles I lost to a *parliamentary* faction, which while not democratic by modern standards was the direct predecessor to modern democratic government. I've not heard of any of his "progress ideas"?

Comment: Perhaps "mental illness" wasn't thought of as a medical condition, but madness was certainly recognized.  For instance Roman Emperors Nero and Caligula.

Comment: @CElliott  pray instruct  us as to why Monarchy was not rejected (in the sense that a formal magna carta equivalent was established which removed the divine right of kings to rule ) in Persia ( Achaemenids Parthians, and Sasanians) nor in Ottoman empire, Ptolemaic Egypt, (before 1700s)  China, Korea, Japan (a bit weird as there was a shogun which ruled in practice as well as an emperor who ruled  in name)
(Gauls, Germanic tribes, Aztec, Mongols also  potential candidates for divine right of kings )